# Get Rows and Columns From Input Box

Tags: vba, excel

**Background Information**

I have an inputbox to get a date from my user to process the sub procedure.

**Problems**

1. I have trouble getting the rows and columns from the inputted value.
2. How do I return the results at the row the user selected instead of a fixed spot a `cells(1, columns.count)`
3. I tried using .address to find the rows and columns. But it returns `invalid qualifier` could you please explain why?

---

```
Sub functionLoop()
  Dim Nextoffday As Date
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim selectionRow As String

  Nextoffday = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the second off day.", Title:="Pick second off day", Type:=8)

  For i = 1 To 30
    If AFPDAY(Nextoffday + i) <> "" Then
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = AFPDAY(Nextoffday + i)
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the address of the cell user selected, try using the following code:

```
Dim Nextoffday As Range 'defining Nextoffday as range instead of date

Set Nextoffday = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the second off day.", Title:="Pick second off day", Type:=8) 'setting it to the user selected cell

MsgBox Nextoffday.Address ' .address will return the address of the cell selected by user

MsgBox Format(Nextoffday.Value, "mm.dd.yyyy") 'will convert the value in date format
```

`Selection.Address` will returns the cell reference of the active selected cell.

Comment: Woah! It's so simple! I tried using range yesterday but it didn't work. Probably because I didn't use `set` to declare the object. I know how to answer question 2 and 3.  Thanks mate!